# NSCoding save NSMutableArray on shutdown and load on startup

Tags: ios, xcode, load, save, nscoding

I am trying to save a NSMutableArray when the app shuts down, and then load it on startup to a tableview.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:_savedText forKey:@"savedText"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
if((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) {
    _savedText = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"savedText"];
}
return self;
}
```

I use this code to save the MutableArray:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_savedText];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"savedText"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And this to load it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSData *savedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedText"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData];
    array = [_savedText copy];
}
```

There are no errors, but the table view is empty on startup. Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the data from the defaults and set to _savedText object. You are reading the data into var named `array` and then assigning `array = [_savedText copy]`. This will probably be nil. It should be the reverse.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSData *savedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedText"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData];
    _savedText = [array copy];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now when I try to create a new row in the table view the app crashes. What can be the reason?